# What key do we use for app engine GCM backend?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to get my app engine project to send out gcm messages. I've gone through the project walkthrough, but am not sure what kind of key I need. I think I need a "browser" key:

[image]

My app engine project has a url like "https://example.appspot.com/". When creating a browser key, what should I enter for the "Accept requests from these HTTP referers (web sites)" section? They give an example of:

```
*.example.com/*
```

so I'm trying:

```
*.example.appspot.com/*
```

But I still get a 401 Unauthorized response when trying to send:

```
Sender sender = new Sender("myBrowserApiKey");
sender.sendNoRetry(...);
```

Right, does anyone know what we're supposed to be using here? I don't think the other key types (Server key, Android key, iOS key) are what I want, because my app engine project doesn't have a static ip, nor am I sending messages directly from my android or ios clients.

Thanks

http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/http.html

http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html

-------- Update ---------------

I went ahead and tried "Server key", and left the whitelists empty. When you save the key with the empty whitelist, you'll see it display "Any IP allowed". After saving, the messages started going through ok about 15 minutes later.

So I guess "server key" is the right one to use if you've got the same setup as me.

Comment: Server Key is the correct one and keeping it open is what you want to do if you want any device to be able to call it. If you are creating a more secured application, IE only for specific offices/ locations you specify the IP's. I think google should be more specific about this.